# jQuery ability to handle changing id for element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use jQuery to hide a button with the below id. I know how to do that with .hide() but what I don't know is how to handle the case where the id of this button changes.

```
id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.MyWork.Home.Tasks.MarkComplete-Large"
```

I know that the id of an DOM element has to be unique, and in this case, I know for certain that Ribbon.ContextualTabs.MyWork.Home.Tasks.MarkComplete will not change. However, I see that it can take on -Small or -Medium or -Large depending on the size of the browser window.

How does one handle this? Would a regular expression work?

Comment: Changing IDs is normally indicative of a poor approach. What you're describing look far more like candidates for class names or data attributes. If you have any control over this, stick with a constant ID and farm the other epithets out as classes or attributes

Comment: I totally agree with you. However, this id is populated by canned Microsoft SharePoint JavaScript as part of a tab creation function. So until I get hired by MS and fix it, this is something I will have to live with.

Comment: SharePoint... urgh... I feel your pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's for sure gonna be one of them 3 you can cover all like this:

```
$('#Ribbon.ContextualTabs.MyWork.Home.Tasks.MarkComplete-Small, #Ribbon.ContextualTabs.MyWork.Home.Tasks.MarkComplete-Medium, #Ribbon.ContextualTabs.MyWork.Home.Tasks.MarkComplete-Large').hide();
```

Utkanos is right though, you shouldn't have changing ids.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just select them all, because there is only one of this button at every size nonetheless, isn't it?

```
$("#"+id+"-Large, #"+id+"-Medium, #"+id+"-Small").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put another attribute on the button that doesn't change (like `name` that could be unique to the button)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below way to hide your element when id has `**"."**` in it

```
$("#Ribbon\\.ContextualTabs\\.MyWork\\.Home\\.Tasks\\.MarkComplete-Large").hide();
```